# Plugin product random behavior

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin, building it with Maven 3.5 and looking at the size of the final product I noticed that the size of the final folder varies in terms of Mbs(1-5 Mbs).
Investigating further I found that the folder that always is different is: plugin_version\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi. Depending on the build, there are missing folders.

I always run `clean install` and before the command I always delete the `.m2` folder from my user profile to make sure that I have the same content.

What can I do to trace down the problem or what may cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/`** folder **should not be part of your product** you ship, but will be generated the first time you launch your application. The size depends on the started plug-ins, which depends on the functions used.

Make sure to pack/copy your product before running it, including (UI) tests. Alternatively, you can use the [`-configuration`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) command line argument to not mess up your configuration area.

If you build your application via [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html), do not forget the `-roaming` argument.

Comment: Is it only the `org.eclipse.osgi` folder that I should care of or are there other folders generated at runtime stored in `configuration` that I should remove/pack before they are generated?

Comment: Most `configuration` content is generated after the first start and should not be shipped. But there are also subfolders like `org.eclipse.update` that are required. You can use the [-configuration](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) command line argument to not mess up the `configuration` folder.

Comment: The product is built on top of eclipse and it is shipped as an eclipse application actually and during the maven build in one of the pom's I have an `-installIUs` command so it looks something like this: `%PRUDUCT_PATH%/eclipse.exe -installIUs <list_of_plugins> -destination %PRODUCT_PATH%`. As a result, during the maven build, the eclipse is opened for a short period of time then it's closing. Therefore in my configuration I assume there are some mandatory files which will corrupt the product if I remove the configuration folder.

Comment: If you build your application via [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) do not forget the `-roaming` argument (see my edited answer above).

Comment: I will give it a try with the **-roaming** option and see the results. To conclude this in order to be able to accept this answer, if the variatinos of size come only from the **org.eclipse.osgi**, I shouldn't be worried because those are the components that are loaded at first run of the application (but I should investigate on that in order to don't deliver a product which is already run by me).

Comment: You are right, an already run/used configuration area should not be moved to a different location (and therefor not be shipped). You did well not to ignore the different sizes. ;-)